# Single queue for jQuery animate() elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

By default the jQuery queue that is created for animate() is done per element, I'm wondering if there is a way to create a single queue for all animations done with animate()? I.e. only one animation should be occuring at a time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with your own custom queue on one element using queue:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRawX/2/

```
$(function(){

    $('#myQueue')
        .queue('myQueue',function(next){
            $('#t1').animate({left: 100}, 
                            {duration: 1000, 
                             queue: false,
                             complete: next
                            })
        })
        .queue('myQueue',function(next){
            $('#t2').animate({left: 100}, 
                            {duration:1000, 
                             queue:false,
                             complete: next})
        })
        /* etc. */
        .dequeue('myQueue')
})
```

Comment: Closest to what I'm trying to acheive

Comment: BTW You can remove the `queue: false` in this case (revision 2 of this answer)

Comment: @Jeffery that depends.  If you intend to have other animations going on outside of this queue then you want the `queue:false`

Comment: "only one animation should be occuring at a time" - it doesn't sound like there are other animations happening to me

Comment: That's fine, I still like this way better as a general solution since the queue acts independently of other queues.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what's going on with those "complete: next"s? I know that they're causing the queue to dequeue after the chain is started, but I don't understand how. What is next referring to? Where does this behavior come from?

Comment: Got it: "In jQuery 1.4 the function that's called is passed in another function, as the first argument, that when called automatically dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving. You would use it like so:"  @ http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(someElement) // could also be a plain object, e.g. $({})
    .queue('customQueue', function (next) {
        first.animate({ ... }, function () {
            // when the animation is complete, call next() for customQueue
            next();
        });
    })
    .queue('customQueue', function (next) {
        second.animate({ ... }, function () {
            // when the animation is complete, call next() for customQueue
            next();
        });
    })
    // add more animations, then
    .dequeue('customQueue');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.animate()` has a `queue` option that will only allow one effect per element:

> queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately.

#### Usage

```
$('div').animate({ height: 50, queue: false });
```

Comment: Doesn't that remove the queue all together rather than create a single one for all elements?